# How to find LAN ip address of android device?

Tags: android

If wifi of device is connected, I assume the device has an LAN IP address assigned presumably by a dhcp running on a router.

How can find it what's the LAN ip address (not the external ip) on the wifi interface ?

Thanks,

Comment: **"If wifi of device is connected, I assume the device has an LAN IP address assigned presumably by a dhcp running on a router."** - Not necessarily. Although the answer from ariefbayu will help you find the IP addresses of various network interfaces, you cannot assume the IP address of a wifi interface is one from a LAN. There are "wide-area" wifi services in various countries - this means if your requirement is to communicate with an actual wifi LAN, your software may not work if the user's device is connected to a "wide-area" wifi network.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[NetworkInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/NetworkInterface.html) will help you:

```
String ipAddress = null;
try {
    for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
        NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
        for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
            InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
            if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                ipAddress = inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
            }
        }
    }
} catch (SocketException ex) {}
```

Comment: Won't this also return a WAN adress if connected with 3G/4G?

Comment: as far as I understand, you will only have one IP based on what's currently connected. If using WIFI, local LAN is what you get. If using 3G/4G, WAN is that you get.

Comment: Hm. In case (wifi) tethering is enabled there should be two adresses. What do you think?

Comment: isn't when the android is in tethering mode, the wifi module gets disabled?

Comment: With my nexus I can tether my WAN connection to a WIFI connection (where the phone is also the access point). I never checked what the networking api is returning in this case. I also never checked whats going on when the mobile is dual-sim.  I'm not sure how we coped to mimic the connection state of Androids topbar in our app