# Android Server Socket

Tags: android, sockets, server

I am unable to reach the Android Server on the emulator from a program on my desktop, how do I solve it?

Some code (from [How to find LAN ip address of android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436181/how-to-find-lan-ip-address-of-android-device)):

```
public static ArrayList<String> getSelfIP(){
    try {
        ArrayList<String> ipList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    ipList.add(inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString());
                }
            }
        }

        return ipList;
    } catch (SocketException ex) {}
    return null;
}
```

The result is `[fe80::5054:ff:fe12:3456%eth0, 10.0.2.15]`

What do I have to configure or do to make the emulator reachable by my desktop programs?

I have done the following:

`> adb forward tcp:50000 tcp:50000`

However, I am unable to access the server through localhost:50000.

Comment: Why so difficult? See here: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html  But much easier is to use a real device.

Comment: I have updated the question with the forwarding ADB command, which does not seem to work.

Comment: Which ip and port do you use to connect to the server on the emulator? On which port your server is listening?

Comment: Emulator Server is listening at tcp port 50000. I have tried both 10.0.2.1 and 10.0.2.15 to no avail.

Comment: Are you sure the server is listening on port 50000?
Try this command: adb devices -l
to see the port number of the emulator you are using.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the ip address **10.0.2.2**.

It is the Special alias to your host loopback interface (i.e., 127.0.0.1 on your development machine)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html) Android documentation, Section "Using Network Redirection".

> **Setting up Redirection through the Emulator Console**
>
> Each emulator instance provides a control console the you can connect
>   to, to issue commands that are specific to that instance. You can use
>   the redir console command to set up redirection as needed for an
>   emulator instance.
>
> First, determine the console port number for the target emulator
>   instance. For example, the console port number for the first emulator
>   instance launched is 5554. Next, connect to the console of the target
>   emulator instance, specifying its console port number, as follows:
>
> `telnet localhost 5554`
>
> Once connected, use the redir command to work
>   with redirection. To add a redirection, use:
>
> `add <protocol>:<host-port>:<guest-port>`
>
> where `<protocol>` is either tcp
>   or udp, and `<host-port>` and `<guest-port>` sets the mapping between your
>   own machine and the emulated system, respectively.
>
> For example, the following command sets up a redirection that handles
>   all incoming TCP connections to your host (development) machine on
>   127.0.0.1:5000 and will pass them through to the emulated system's 10.0.2.15:6000:
>
> `redir add tcp:5000:6000`

In your case the last command would be

```
redir add tcp:5000:5000
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue once, use 10.0.2.2 IP adress it should solve your problem.